# How do RGB colors work?

Tags: optics, visible-light, fourier-transform

They say that all colors can be formed by mixing Red, Green, and Blue appropriately. Is it true? Isn't the Fourier basis infinite dimensional? Or does it turn out to be the case that only three frequencies happen to reproduce most of the colors in the visible range?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are colors?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24263/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can colors be mixed?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/108783/)

Comment: Thanks for the links. What is the normal protocol for an author if he discovers that his question is a duplicate? Delete his question?