# how does different colour wavelength intefere?

Tags: visible-light, waves, spectroscopy

Say a red colour with 400nm mixes with blue colour with 700nm, but out of phase by a little. What would be the resultant colour?

I would know how to represent the resulting wave mathematically, but what colour is it? Is the colour only determined by the resulting wavelength?

Comment: when you mix colors as the rainbow colors, i.e. two frequencies, the individual frequencies remain. That is how the rainbow appears from a prism, it separates the individual frequencies. If you are mixing paints it is color perception and goes to biology. It will also be true with lasers of these wavelengths, the mix will be color perception, not interference. as with old test polaroid cameras with two colors only.

Comment: I meant mixing rainbow colours. what colour would be the combined frequency wave? Is there a way to calculate it?

Comment: you have to go to another forum. When frequencies are mixed the results depend on the cells of the retina of the eye. The two frequencies coexist without interfering or adding.  It is the eye/brain that does the adding http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwin_H._Land#Later_years  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_vision

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can colors be mixed?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/108783/)